# How to overwrite all files only if SAME size and exact duplicate while renaming if different size?

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-transfer, duplicate, deduplication

I'm using Teracopy, but Windows also does not have this function. Instead it wants me to replace the file only if DIFFERENT, or skip it if the name is the same. I want to do the opposite.

I need to rename files that are different with same name, and only overwrite if the file is the SAME as in an exact duplicate.

I have about 20 million files in different folders and I want to merge all the folders and remove all duplicates in the process.

I don't want `Overwrite All` which will lose different files with the same names. Definitely do not want that, as many have the same names but are different files. I do not want to lose any updates or changes.

I also don't want to `Skip All`, which will ignore files with the same name even if they are the same file, which is the whole point - to remove them.

The function I want is not listed.

How can I merge these folders of files only replacing files that have the same name and size (remove exact duplicates), while renaming files that are different but have the same name?

[image]